# How to set header exectaly above the particular content in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I used checkbox and switches in my custom tableview cell. But as shown in the image i need to place the header at the proper place above the checkbox and switch.

How should i suppose to do this.

Thanks in advance.

[image: how to place header above the checkbox and switch.]

Comment: Create a .xib file, customise it and put it in `viewForHeader` method.

Comment: I used the xib file to create the cell and used constraints. So it will automatically adjust according to the device view. So how i dynamically put the heading in header view to put it exactly above them. ?

Comment: Did you use `viewForHeaderInSection ` method?

Comment: I tried to use the same but the header is not aligning according to the switch and checkbox. Some time got left and some time go right.

Comment: Do you thing, I will customize the first row and place custom created label above those checkbox and switch in it and start to fill data from second row. Is this the right approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps for achieving your task.

1. Add a `UITableViewController` to your `storyboard`
2. Create two cell in your `UITableView`
3. First cell identifier take as `headerCell` and second cell identifier take as `listCell`
4. Take two label inside your first cell
5. Now it's time to set constraint first `controller click on right label` and drag it to first cell and set it to `vertical center`.
6. Now click on same label and set its constraint from left as 8 as shown in image.
   [image: Check It]
7. Set same for Label two which is Selectable.
8. Now comes with the new cell which is called as `listCell` see the image and set all constraint as shown in image. [image: check this]
9. Also don't forget to set width to both label which in header cell.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need a custom tableview header as well.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return YOUR_CUSTOM_HEADER_VIEW
}
```

[image]

Comment: I used the xib file to create the cell and used constraints. So it will automatically adjust according to the device view. So how i dynamically put the heading in header view to put it exactly above them. ?

Comment: Creating a view similar to my edited answer. If you use constraints for your custom `UITableViewCell`, you can apply the similar constraints to your custom header view too.